# "A Brief History of the World" - what are the area values over the epochs?

Tags: brief-history-of-the-world

I got "A Brief History of the World" second hand, and I'm not entirely sure if the area value tokens are all there. The area values are not listed anywhere else in the rule book or on the internet as far as I could find. And not every area has a token for each epoch by design, absent tokens for that epoch indicate an area value of 0, so there is no way to check if a token is missing or supposed to not exist.

Can someone with a known-good 'A Brief History of the World' post a table with area values for the epochs?

I specifically only have two tokens for the second epoch, only for north and south Europe.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe There are a number of editions of History of the World, of which "A Brief History of the World" is one. A tag history-of-the-world is probably more useful for the site than brief-history-of-the-world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After verifying that the area values of my box are complete, here they are if anyone else is wondering the same (or lost some of the tokens)

```
Epoch             1   2   3   4   5   6

Northern Europe       1   2           3
Southern Europe   1   2   3           2
North Africa      2                   1
Southern Africa                   1   2
Middle East       3                   2
India             2       3           2
Australasia                       1   2
South East Asia           1   2  
China             2       3           2
Eurasia                       1       2
Japan                     1           2
North America                 1   2   3
South America                 1   2
```

NB 'Eurasia' is labeled 'Asia' on the map

Answer (score 4):

According to [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/46007/brief-history-world) these are the contents of the game:

- Giant Map Board
- 180 plastic playing pieces
- 130 card counters
- 32 Area Values

  - - 5 x Epoch 1
  - - 2 x Epoch 2
  - - 6 x Epoch 3 (BGG has 3, but that is a typo).
  - - 4 x Epoch 4
  - - 4 x Epoch 5
  - - 11 x Epoch 6
- 30 City/Capitals
- 20 Monuments (4 types x 5)
- 20 Forts
- 18 Bonus tokens (1's, 2's 3's - 6 of each)
- 6 Gold Markers (1 in each player colour)
- 4 Fleets
- 42 Empire cards (6 epochs, 7 cards per epoch)
- 54 Event cards (6 epochs, 7 cards per epoch, plus 12 initial events)
- 6 Epoch maps
- 6 Six sided dice
- 4 Plastic Stands
- 1 Epoch chart
- 1 Array

There are 32 area value tokens, specified by epoch.

Comment: Great! While my box also lists the contents it doesn't specify the number of area values. This means my set is complete, I'll post a table myself.

Comment: But the area values for epoch 3 is wrong. I have 6 of them, which makes the total add to 32 so probably a typo on boardgamegeeks.

Comment: Lol, you are right ;-)